# Tengo un error Vuejs me muestra consola pero en vista -- laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**Template.html**

```
<div class="container">
      <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre completo</th>
      <th scope="col">Telefono</th>
      <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
      <th scope="col">Pago</th>
      <th scope="col">Opciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in orden.data"  >
      <th scope="row">{{ item.id}}</th>
      <td>{{item.name}}  {{item.last_name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Celular}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Direccion}}</td>
      <td>{{item.pay}}</td>
      <td> <button type="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" v-on:click="showgetcompra(item)">Reporte</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div v-for="items in vercompra.data">
                    <h1>hola {{items.Orden["0"].Img_Produ}}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<pagination data="orden" @pagination -change-page="fetchData"></pagination>
```

**Script.JS**

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.fetchData(),
            this.showgetcompra(),
            this.timer = setInterval(

                this.fetchData, 10000)
            console.log(this.timer)
        },
        data ( ){
            return {
                orden: [],
                vercompra:[],
                timer: '',
                loading: false

            }
        },
        methods:{

            fetchData(page){

                if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
                    page = 1;
                }

                axios.get('/api/cart?page='+page)
                .then((res)=>{

                    this.orden = res.data
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })
            },
            cancelAutoUpdate: function() { 
                clearInterval(this.timer) 
            },

             beforeDestroy() {
             clearInterval(this.timer)
             },

             showgetcompra: function(item){

                 axios.get('/api/cart/'+item.id)
                .then((res)=>{

                    this.vercompra = res.data
                    console.log(res.data)
                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })
             },
             eliminarcompras(){

             }

        }

    }
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si puedes pon el error que te lanza VueJs exactamente el que se muestra en rojo en tu imagen al comienzo de los datos de la consola.

Comment: no de ese error no tengo problemas tengo el del paso de datos reporte al modal

Comment: showgetcompra: function(item){
                 
                 axios.get('/api/cart/'+item.id)
                .then((res)=>{
                    
                    this.vercompra = res.data
                    console.log(res.data.Orden["0"].Valor_Produ)
                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err)
                })
             }

Answer (score 0):

He visto que estás haciendo un `console.log` de `res.data`, luego la variable `this.vercompra` ya tiene res.data

Aquí hay dos posibilidades, ya que es un objeto y no un array, no puedes hacer el v-for.

1. Posibilidad:

Si dentro de Orden hay un array:

```
<div v-for="item in vercompra.Orden">
    <h1>hola {{item.Img_Produ}}</h1>
</div>
```

2. Posibilidad:

`<h1>hola {{vercompra.Orden["0"].Img_Produ}}</h1>
 <h1>hola {{vercompra.Pago}}</h1>`

Comment: no me funciono sigue sin aparecer datos

Comment: Te he editado la respuesta,  si puedes hacerme captura de lo que hay dentro de Orden, Pago, etc te podré ayudar mejor. Dime también que buscas mostrar, si Orden solo, Pago, todo... y te doy respuesta exacta.